# Python3 script in crontab in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, cron, ubuntu-14.04

```
eric@eric:~/project$ tree -d
.
|-- env
|   |-- bin
|   |-- include
|   |   `-- python3.4m -> /usr/include/python3.4m
|   `-- lib
|       `-- python3.4
|           |-- collections -> /usr/lib/python3.4/collections
|           |-- config-3.4dm-x86_64-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4dm-x86_64-linux-gnu
|           |-- config-3.4m-x86_64-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m-x86_64-linux-gnu
|           |-- distutils
|           |   `-- __pycache__
|           |-- encodings -> /usr/lib/python3.4/encodings
|           |-- importlib -> /usr/lib/python3.4/importlib
|           |-- lib-dynload -> /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload
|           |-- plat-x86_64-linux-gnu -> /usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
|           |-- __pycache__
|           `-- site-packages
|               ...  # removed thirdparty libraries just to make it more readable
|               |-- pip-1.5.6.dist-info
|               |-- __pycache__
|               |-- setuptools
|               |   |-- command
|               |   |   `-- __pycache__
|               |   |-- __pycache__
|               |   `-- tests
|               |       `-- __pycache__
|               `-- setuptools-3.6.dist-info
`-- myscript.py
```

so in home directory there is a folder named project. in project folder I have a virtualenv folder and a simple script(let's say hello world in python3)

`which python3` gives `/usr/bin/python3`

Now I'm trying to run this script using `crontab -e` (ubuntu 14.04).
I can run this script manually by activating virtualenv (`source env/bin/activate`) but I've no idea how should I do this thing in crontab and what would be the shebang for this python3 virtualenv.

PS: I'm able to run a python2 script in crontab by adding this shebang `#!/usr/bin/python` at top of the file and then this line in crontab -e (run everyday at 2PM )

```
00 14 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/eric/project/myscript.py >> /var/log/cronjob.log
```

PPS: I dont want to write setup.py and use setuptools just a natural way (as I did above for python2)

Comment: what is python3 specific about it? have you tried the obvious `/path/to/env/bin/python /path/to/script.py ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you want to run your script with `python3` from `virtualenv`.

If so, you should use this path in your `crontab -e`: `/home/eric/project/env/bin/python` (figure out the exact path, if this one doesn't work).

I think, shebang has no nothing to do here, once you specify python binary explicitly.